# Windows Embeded Compact 7 - using batch file - ERRORLEVEL not possible?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-ce, errorlevel

I tried to write an batch file using ERRORLEVEL.
Unfortunatly it´s not working (or better not working the way I expect).

It seems to be that ERRORLEVEL is not available as an environment variable.

on cmd:
if %errorlevel% == 0 echo test

result:
no echo

on cmd:
if %errorlevel% == %errorlevel% echo test

result:
test

on cmd:
echo %errorlevel%

result:
%errorlevel%

Read about using setlocal, but setlocal cannot be executed

Any ideas?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use the old syntax see `if /?`. The command `ìf errorlevel  1` means greater or equal to one.

Comment: I have written really many batch files, but never used `%ERRORLEVEL%` in an __IF__ condition as not needed at all. See the Microsoft support article [Testing for a Specific Error Level in Batch Files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/69576). In general `if errorlevel 1` for exit code of previous command/application greater or equal 1 or `if not errorlevel 1` for exit code equal 0 (or lower) is enough and working also within a command block without delayed expansion. I don't know of any application which exits with a negative value. That would be against all OS guidelines for exit values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ERRORLEVEL` requires a process or function to be carried out in order to display an input. Say for instance you wanted to Ping Google and if successful it would print out "Good" or if it failed printed out "Bad", that's where `ERRORLEVEL` would come into effect. You cannot use `ERRORLEVEL` if a process or function is not present.

EX.

```
echo off
goto :pingtest
cls

:pingtest
cls
ping www.google.com 
if errorlevel 2 goto :good
if errorlevel 1 echo :bad

:good
cls
echo Good
echo[
pause

:bad
cls
echo Bad
echo[
pause
```

As you can see from the code above, there was a process involved.

**Also if you get the chance could you check out my blog?** http://pryrotech.weebly.com

Comment: Thank you, as it seems not all commands give an errorlevel as result. I would adapt the batch-file using "IF EXIST" to doublecheck if an file is present. Thanx to all for supporting.